# If Parashurama is immortal, why did Narada tell Yudhisthira that he will fall prey to death?

Tags: mahabharata, parashurama

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07067.htm

> "Narada said, 'Even the great ascetic Rama, the hero worshipped by all heroes, that son of Jamadagni, of great fame, will die, without being contented (with the period of his life).

Comment: Everyone dies/merges with Brahman at the end of the world.

Comment: But he will live a very long time though, I think